# Can't get MLP to work in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network

I tried this code to input an image into a network:

```
Mat img = imread("img.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat output(1,1,CV_32FC1, {{1}});
cout << output.size() << endl;
resize(img, img, Size(16,16));
img = img.reshape(1,1);
Mat input(1,256, CV_32FC1);
input.row(0) = img;

Mat layers(2,1,CV_32SC1);
layers.row(0) = Scalar(256);
layers.row(1) = Scalar(1);

CvANN_MLP mlp;
CvANN_MLP_TrainParams params;
CvTermCriteria criteria;
criteria.max_iter = 100;
criteria.epsilon = 0.00001f;
criteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
params.train_method = CvANN_MLP_TrainParams::BACKPROP;
params.bp_dw_scale = 0.05f;
params.bp_moment_scale = 0.05f;
params.term_crit = criteria;

mlp.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1,1);

mlp.train(input, output, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

But I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (input matrix must have the same number of columns as the number of neurons in the input layer) in predict, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ml/src/ann_mlp.cpp, line 283
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/ml/src/ann_mlp.cpp:283: error: (-201) input matrix must have the same number of columns as the number of neurons in the input layer in function predict
```

As you see, `input` is `1x256` and network has `256` neurons in input layer, but I get error that input network is not OK.

Comment: it's complaining about the input to predict, not train, so please append the piece of code, where you try to predict the test img

Comment: WOW! I didn't notice that, my bad! thanQ :D

Comment: you'll see, it'll be all easy. the test img has to be processed the very same way as the train images. once we see the difference, the answer will be straightforward

Comment: Absolutely. Sometimes we have to go back and see the whole thing, which is hard when you're working alone.

Comment: sounds, like you solved it on your own already ;)